# How to have a set of enumeration values in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, set

Assume i [have an enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx):

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
   public enum DialogResult { None, OK, Cancel, Abort, Retry, Ignore, Yes, No }
}
```

i want to declare a *"set"* made up of these enumerated types

```
ShowForm(Form frm, DialogResults allowedResults)
```

In other languages you would declare:

```
public DialogResults = set of DialogResult;
```

And then i can use

```
ShowForm(frm, DialogResult.OK | DialogResult.Retry);
```

C# has the notion of ***Flags***, pseudocode:

```
[Flags]
public enum DialogResults { DialogResult.None, DialogResult.OK, DialogResult.Cancel, DialogResult.Abort, DialogResult.Retry, DialogResult.Ignore, DialogResult.Yes, DialogResult.No }
```

problem with that it's not real code - `Flags` does not instruct the compiler to create a set of flags.

- in one case the type should only allow **one** value (`DialogResult`)
- in another case the type should allow multiple values of above (`DialogResults`)

How can i have a *"set"* of enumerated types?

> **Note**: i assume it's not possible in C#. If that's the answer: it's okay to say so - the question is answered.
>
> **Note**: Just because i believe C# language doesn't have the feature doesn't mean it doesn't have the feature - i may just not have found it yet.

---

**Update:** another example:

Assume i have an enumeration:

```
public enum PatronTier 
{ 
    Gold = 1,      
    Platinum = 2,  
    Diamond = 3,   
    SevenStar = 7  //Yes, seven
}
```

i want to declare a *"set"* made up of these enumerated types

```
public Tournament
{
   public PatronTiers EligibleTiers { get; set; }
}
```

In other languages you would declare:

```
public PatronTiers = set of PatronTier;
```

And then i can use:

```
tournament.EligibleTiers = PatronTier.Gold | PatronTier.SevenStar;
```

C# has the notion of ***Flags***, pseudocode:

```
[Flags]
public enum PatronTiers { PatronTier.Gold, PatronTier.Platinum, PatronTier.Diamond, PatronTier.SevenStar }
```

problem with that it's not real code.

How can i have a *"set"* of enumerated types?

Comment: Is there a problem with `HashSet<PatronTiers>`?

Comment: `public Boolean MarriageValid` Hoo boy, not touching that example. :P

Comment: You seem to be trying to find an area between a [Flags]-based enumeration and an array or list of the enumerated type (e.g. List<PatronTier>).  There is no such concept in C#, you'll need to use a collection of some kind, or use the [Flags] attribute on your enumeration.

Comment: `[Flags]
public enum DialogResult { None = 0, OK = 1, Cancel = 2, Abort = 4, Retry = 8, Ignore = 16, Yes = 32, No = 64 }` ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't pass around a HashSet<YourEnumType>?

Comment: Do you have some kind of problem with same sex marriages?

Comment: @JeffN825 Bit the bullet and edited the questionable stuff out :-)

Comment: @JeffN825 Just because a state government dictates a policy, doesn't mean i have to agree with it. But the customer (a university) requires the software to have these checks. They can't just ignore the legal requirement, and i can't ignore a customer's requirement. Also M/F is a common enumeration situation - so i thought it would be helpful to have an enumeration everyone's dealt with.

Comment: @vc74 i thought about tagging the question; but in the past people have gotten grumpy when i do that

Comment: @JohnSaunders There might be nothing wrong with `HashSet<PatronTiers>`; i've never used `HashSet` before. i'll let you know after i try Adam's answer.

Comment: Honestly, I was just kidding around.

Comment: @IanBoyd That's too bad, every now and then I miss Pascal's sets too and then in operator...

Comment: @JohnSaunders There is a problem with HashSet, you can't assign them (it copies references).

Comment: What do you mean you can't assign them, and what's the problem with copying references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want an array of things. There are array types in C#, but nothing that is *directly* equivalent to your examples in terms of compiler support, closest is perhaps `DialogResults[]`, an array of `DialogResults`.

Try supplying a `HashSet` of the items you allow. `HashSet<T>` implements `ISet<T>`, and it's usually best to work against interfaces than concrete types, especially for method signatures:

```
ShowForm(Form frm, ISet<DialogResults> allowedResults);
```

Then you can use `Contains` to test for items:

```
if (allowedResults.Contains(DialogResults.OK))
{
}
```

**Somewhat pointless alternative:** you could always implement your own `Set<Enum>` type using [Jon Skeet's Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) to give you a nicer syntax from the perspective of the caller and get a little closer to your examples.

Comment: +1 but the method parameter should be of type `ISet<DialogResults>` to permit the passing of other classes that implement `ISet<DialogResults>`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Didn't even realise there was an `ISet<>` interface, updated my answer to suit.

Comment: Hmm. i had an alias that defined the type (`public class PrizeEligibleTiers : HashSet<PatronTier> {};`) What would be the `ISet<>` version of he `PrizeEligibleTiers` alias?

Comment: @IanBoyd: that's not an alias, that's a derived type. Since `HashSet<T>` already implements `ISet<T>`, you would not need to change that derived class.

Comment: @JohnSaunders But i would still like an alias so that i don't have to update source code when i change a type used globally (i.e. doesn't matter what PrizeEligibleTiers is, as long as it is) (Because i already have code that uses `PrizeEligibleTiers` and that type can keep that name, juts mean something else)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean by "alias". An alternative I like is to use "var" instead of an explicit type name, whenever possible. It greatly helps reduce the amount of code that has to change whenever the type changes.

Comment: i was trying to figure out why `HashSet<T>` didn't implement `ISet<T>`. Then i realized that `HashSet<T>` **doesn't** implement `ISet<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: @IanBoyd 4.0 is your friend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Whoa whoa whoa, slow down there speedy. i'm hoping nobody will freak out that i bumped this project from 2.0 to 3.5SP1.

Comment: @IanBoyd It'll only be a headache for system admins if automatic updates for Windows are disabled :-) Simple answer, if you don't have the interface, just use `HashSet<T>` directly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't suppose you just mean using something like this?

```
var DialogResults = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DialogResult));
```

with a `.Select(dr => (DialogResult)dr).ToArray()` if you want it strongly typed.

Comment: with a `.Cast<DialogResult>().ToArray()` if you want it strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
foreach (var item in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(PatronTier)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```